# Creating a new Trac project via trac-admin initenv

Tags: trac

I'm somewhat new to Trac. 
I'm running trac version 0.11.7 on an ubuntu system.

I'm trying to create another project via the following command:

"trac-admin /var/lib/trac/shipping_tracker initenv".

After answering the various questions, the program fails and returns an error
( see: http://pastebin.com/yijzpB3i ) "Table 'system' already exists"

Does this mean that every-time I need to create a new project, I'll have to go into 
the mysql database and create a new database, like trac1, trac2, etc??

I did notice this particular ticket ( http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/5138 ) where 
someone states you have to create a new database for each project. Is this correct??

Thank you.

--Mike

Answer (score 2):

Every Trac environment, being a completely self-contained space, uses a separate database. So yes, you need to create a new database for each environment (although it might be a bad idea to name them `trac1`, `trac2` etc.).

If you want to create new environments often, what you really need is probably [multi-project support](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/Proposals/MultipleProject), which allows you to have different projects within one environment. However, it is still not done as of Trac 0.13, and is planned for 0.14.

You might also want to read about [various ideas on having multiple projects with Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMultipleProjects). One of them deals with making Trac store [multiple environments in a single database](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMultipleProjects/MultipleEnvironmentsSingleDatabase), though it might be outdated and probably breaks automatic updates.

Comment: Hi Helgi, Thank you for the response. Makes sense and I suppose I'll have to wait for Trac 0.14 then. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Trac 1.0, running as a stand-alone server, and in order to run multiple projects on one trac installation you still need to set up new environment using

```
trac-admin /path/to/trac/yournewpoject initenv
```

... then create .htpasswd file in the `/path/to/trac/yournewpoject` dir, add users using

```
htpasswd /path/to/trac/yournewpoject/.htpasswd newuser
```

(or copy an existing .htpasswd file there) ... and then restart trac with similar to the followin command:

```
python /path/to/tracd --user=yourlinuxuser --group=yourlinuxgroup -d \
-b hostname -p 8000 \
--basic-auth=oldproject,/path/to/trac/oldproject/.htpasswd,realmname \
--basic-auth=yournewpoject,/path/to/trac/yournewpoject/.htpasswd,realmname \
/path/to/trac/oldproject \
/path/to/trac/yournewpoject
```

This is valid in case you are using the same type of basic authentication as I do.