# trac-admin initdev gives error

Tags: windows-7, trac, bitnami

I installed bitnami trac on Windows 7 to `C:\Bitnami\trac-1.0.9-0\` directory. Installation seemed to complete no problem. From command prompt I created a folder called `projects` under `C:\Bitnami\trac-1.0.9-0\`. CD'd to `projects` and typed `trac-admin myproj initdev` where `myproj` doesn't exist (according to the trac documentation it should not). I got this error.

```
Error: No Trac environment found at C:\Bitnami\trac-1.0.9-0\projects\myproj
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Bitnami\\trac-1.0.9-0\\projects\\myproj\\VERSION'
```

What am I doing wrong?

I checked these 2 links [Creating a new Trac project via trac-admin initenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150591/creating-a-new-trac-project-via-trac-admin-initenv), and [trac-admin /path/to/myproject initenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002427/trac-admin-path-to-myproject-initenv) with similar issues but don't seem to address mine.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: You've typed `initdev` rather than `initenv`.

Comment: OMG I'm embarrassed. Thanks.

Comment: The error message isn't exactly informative, but from what I remember there are technical reasons why it's difficult to improve the error message without changing the structure of the commands